# Expose a service externally in TCP/UDP other than Loadbalancer

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I need to

- expose some pods directly on nodes, for TCP & UDP
- be able to access them externally, individually

I would like to avoid creating a loadbancer service for each pod as there is no need of loadbalancing, just the exposure to outside world.

I don see any solution with Service or Ingress.

All this happens in GKE.

Would someone have an idea?

thanks!

Comment: Does `NodePort` matches your needs?

Comment: @SergiiBishyr I tried but my nodeport service is not exposed externally (External-IP says <none>)

Comment: If you do not want to expose the pod to  external world, and just want to access it then , kubectl port-forward might be a way to access the pod.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi I do want to expose it externally

Comment: What about `Ingress`? Why isn't it suitable for you?

Comment: @SergiiBishyr Ingress are for http only for the moment from what I have seen. I need TCP and UDP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your nodes are accessible from the outside world you can get away with just `hostNetwork: true`, there are some potential issues with it though (ie. just one pod per host or potential port conflicts with other stuff on node). You don't need any service defined for it, as it will just listen on your nodes ports (need to have them open on firewall, security policies or whatever guards your nodes from external world).

Any use of service (except for maybe headless one) will result in a loadbalancing between all backing pods (be it ClusterIP, NodePort or LB), but only LB service will give you a dedicated external IP.

Comment: OK I created a pod with hostNetwork:true, opened the ip/port on the firewall, and it works with the public ip of the node. Thanks!